# Shorten repetitive code

Tags: c#

I feel quite dumb asking this but I have two methods which have almost the same code except the naming convention... I want to shorten this to reduce the use of redundant code.
How do I actually shorten this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace empTRUST
{
    class DBDictionary : DBBase
    {
        public DBDictionary()
            : base("Dictionary", "Word")
        {
        }

        public List<DataRow> AngerPercent(string status)
        {
            List<DataRow> dataList = new List<DataRow>();
            var wordPattern = new Regex(@"\w+");
            DataRow[] rows = fbTab.Select("Genre = 'Angry'");
            foreach (Match match in wordPattern.Matches(status))
                foreach (var item in rows)
                    if (item["Word"].ToString().ToLower() == match.ToString().ToLower())
                    {
                        dataList.Add(item);
                    }

            return dataList;
        }

        public List<DataRow> CaringPercent(string status)
        {
            List<DataRow> dataList = new List<DataRow>();
            var wordPattern = new Regex(@"\w+");
            DataRow[] rows = fbTab.Select("Genre = 'Caring'");
            foreach (Match match in wordPattern.Matches(status))
                foreach (var item in rows)
                    if (item["Word"].ToString().ToLower() == match.ToString().ToLower())
                    {
                        dataList.Add(item);
                    }

            return dataList;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: [Better place.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Genre is the only thing that is different so just move it to the list of method arguments:

```
    public List<DataRow> GenrePercent(string status, string genre)
    {
        List<DataRow> dataList = new List<DataRow>();
        var wordPattern = new Regex(@"\w+");
        DataRow[] rows = fbTab.Select(String.Format("Genre = '{0}'", genre.Replace("'", "''")));
        foreach (Match match in wordPattern.Matches(status))
            foreach (var item in rows)
                if (item["Word"].ToString().ToLower() == match.ToString().ToLower())
                {
                    dataList.Add(item);
                }

        return dataList;
    }
```

You can then pass genre name when calling it:

```
    GenrePercent("Status1", "Angry");
    GenrePercent("Status2", "Caring");
```

Comment: From @Hogan's slightly more generic approach, it's obvious that it's the caller's responsibility to ensure that genres containing quotes get escaped properly. Your approach *suggests* that your function handles it, but it doesn't actually handle it.

Comment: Well, there is always room for making this more generic but also one has to consider this is a part of public interface and so there's a question about how much implementation details caller has to know: e.g. format of entire filter expression or only (valid) values for status and genre. I would eventually add here one (more generic) private method which would have parametrized filter.

Comment: Sorry, I can see how you took my comment the way you did, but I didn't mean that you should make your method more generic, nor that you shouldn't. I only meant that if you don't, your function should be the one to handle escaping of special characters.

Comment: What @hvd means here is that `var t = GenrePercent("Status", "Hogan's");` will fail -- but the API implies it will work, whereas in my answer I put that responsibility on the caller.

Answer (score 4):

```
    public List<DataRow> QualifyPercent(string status, string selectQualifier)
    {
        List<DataRow> dataList = new List<DataRow>();
        var wordPattern = new Regex(@"\w+");
        DataRow[] rows = fbTab.Select(selectQualifier);
        foreach (Match match in wordPattern.Matches(status))
            foreach (var item in rows)
                if (item["Word"].ToString().ToLower() == match.ToString().ToLower())
                {
                    dataList.Add(item);
                }

        return dataList;
    }
```

call it like this:

```
    List<DataRow> angerPercent = QualifyPercent(status,"Genre = 'Angry'");
```

---

I believe the code could be made even simpler (this is more of a comment than an answer because it has nothing to do with the original question):

```
public List<DataRow> QualifyPercent(string status, string selectQualifier)
{
   var matchList = status.Split(" ".ToCharArray());

   var dataList = 
       fbTab.Select(selectQualifier).OfType<DataRow>().Select(row => 
         matchList.Select(
            m => m.ToString().ToLower() == row["Word"].ToSring().ToLower()).Any());

       return dataList;
}
```

Love that linq, this should be faster because of the nature of linq `Any()` will only run the loop till a result is found - which should speed it up O(n/2)

Answer (score 1):

You already have one parameter, why not change the bit with `'Caring'` to be based on a parameter as well?

```
public List<DataRow> AngerPercent(string status)
...
   DataRow[] rows = fbTab.Select("Genre = 'Angry'");
```

becomes

```
public List<DataRow> AngerPercent(string status, string query)
...
   DataRow[] rows = fbTab.Select("Genre = '" + query + "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<DataRow> Percent(string status, DataRow[] rows)
{
    List<DataRow> dataList = new List<DataRow>();
    var wordPattern = new Regex(@"\w+");

    foreach (Match match in wordPattern.Matches(status)) {
        foreach (var item in rows) {
            if (item["Word"].ToString().ToLower() == match.ToString().ToLower()) {
                dataList.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    return dataList;
}
```

Call like this:

```
DataRow[] data = fbTab.Select("Genre = 'Angry'");
// DataRow[] data = fbTab.Select("Genre = 'Caring'");

Percent("Status1", data);
```

Your method shouldn't know, what data you would like to pass him- 1 method = 1 function (processing your given data in this case).